# How to use /foo-:bar route in nuxtjs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs

I want to use this router /foo-:bar in nuxt. How can I achieve it. I try pages/foo-_bar.vue but not working.

Answer (score 0):

This requires a custom route, which you could [configure in `nuxt.config.js`](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing/#extendroutes):

```js
module.exports = {
  router: {
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      routes.push({
        name: 'foo',
        path: '/foo-:bar',
        component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/foo-_bar.vue')
      })
    }
  },
}
```